# jQuery POST request actually sends as GET

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, get

I'm trying to use the following code to send a POST request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: 'http://api.com/'+apiUsername+'/'+apiBucket+'/elements/add',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        username: apiUsername,
        api_key: APIkey,
        elementPermalink: tURL
    }),
    success: function() {
        console.log('posted!');
    }
});
```

However, this *always* goes through as a GET request, not a POST request, and the API server consequently rejects it. Why is jQuery insisting on making this a GET request?

(This is intentionally cross-domain, but it's JSONP so that's not a problem.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

JSONP is a GET only so `dataType: 'jsonp',` will always be a get

Think of JSONP like this:

```
<script src="http://url.com/?query=string"></script>
```

Since that's how jsonp gets around cross-domain, it can only be a get request.