# JQuery $.ajax(),$.post() sending GET as Request Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, get

I have gone through all the suggested links to find out the solution but still when I trying to make `$.post()` it sending `GET` as a `Request_Method` and it is giving me error

`GET https://example.com/samewebservice/save 405 (Method Not Allowed)`

It is a Cross Origin Request so I have enable all the CORS setting on server,
If i execute `$.get()` method it is giving me response in JSON format successfully.

But when m trying to execute `$.post()` method it is giving me error.

**POST ajax request**

```
function postAjax(URL,jsonData){

  $.post(URL,jsonData,function(data){
    response = data;
     alert("In success");
     console.log(data);
  },"jsonp");
  return response;
}
```

On browser header I am getting this

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess. Try adding the ***type*** also

```
function postAjax(URL,jsonData){
  $.post(URL,jsonData,
    type:'POST',
    function(data){
      response = data;
      alert("In success");
      console.log(data);
  },
  "jsonp");

  return response;
}
```

B/w the *jsonp* datatype might be the reason here. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7725952/354307)

Comment: Not working,`$.post()` not accept `type:'POST'` as a parameter

Comment: Then you can either change the datatype to 'json' instead of 'jsonp' or change the 'post' function to 'ajax'

Comment: If I use `$.ajax()` method with `datatype:jsonp` and `type:'POST'` it also gives same error as above

Comment: This is a case of cross-domain json object fetching I guess. You can try adding a filter or something. Please check this answer- http://stackoverflow.com/a/26803206/354307

Comment: jQuery library [has type already] in post function (https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.2.4/src/ajax.js#L836), adding it by hand here is useless

Answer (score 1):

You can't POST using JSONP...it creates a `<script>` element to fetch data..which has to be a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

I had a [FromBody] before my "HttpRequestMessage request" parameter; and this wasn't parsing correctly..........